# MySQL select all records that match the same others records in another table

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables: 
Table _**models** with fields *name* and *model_id* 
 And
Table _**tags** with fields *tag_name*, *tags_id* and *model_id*

In my web app, I can assign some tags to a model by adding records in table **_tags** with the model’s *model_id* related field.

How can I SELECT from table **_models** just the models which have the same *tags* assigned in the **_tags** table?

For example, I need to SELECT all the models that have assigned both the tag #jacket and the tag #trench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example, you can use a GROUP BY/HAVING along with a COUNT DISTINCT to find models that have *both* of the tags assigned.

```
SELECT m.model_id, m.name
    FROM models m
        INNER JOIN tags t
            ON m.model_id = t.model_id
    WHERE t.tag_name IN ('#jacket', '#trench')
    GROUP BY m.model_id, m.name
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.tag_name) = 2;
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution of my problem, thank you Joe!

Comment: @fboc Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). You get points for it as well. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way to do the same:

```
SELECT
      m.model_id
    , m.name
FROM
    _models m
WHERE
    2 = (
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            _tags t
        WHERE
                m.model_id = t.model_id
            AND t.tag_name IN ('#jacket', '#trench')
    )
```

Note 1: You would better move tag names to separate table. So 3 tables: models (id, name), tags (id, name), tags2models (tag_id, model_id)

Note 2: Do not forget to add index (tag_name, model_id) on table _tags

Comment: Thank you fifonik! I agree with you! In this case, I wrote just an example of my models and tags tables. In the project I have also a separate table for tags name.